# pointer-events not affecting scrollbars in Firefox & Opera

Tags: css, firefox, opera

I was working on a dropdown menu in CSS when I found something about `pointer-events` in Firefox 44. At first I thought it would be a mistake that happened in new version of Firefox, but I saw the problem in Firefox 25 again, and it also exists in Opera 18 (which is running webkit).

The code itself could be very confusing, so I made another sample:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #DDD;
  /*- overflow-y -*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*- pointer events -*/
  pointer-events: none;
}
div:hover {
  background: #D77;
}
```

```html
<div>
  text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>
</div>
```

As you see, the div element's `pointer-events` property is set to `none`, so we would expect it not to run the `:hover` at all.

But just go ahead and move your cursor on the scrollbar (in Firefox and Opera).

[`pointer-events` is completely supported in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), so what's wrong? Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
 It's solved in newer versions of opera 
but I need It to work at least on all common versions of `chrome`, `opera` and `firefox`
any trick or alternative way?

**EDIT 2:** here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ja0ct9s6/2/
at first look it work's well 
but take your cursor out of it , move it in again from the right side (when you don't see the dropdown) , It look's the scrollbar still hoverable(?) **(remember to use firefox)**

Comment: Just to clarify: Your original concern is to show the scroll bars, but make them inactive, one could say read only. Is that right?

Comment: just a few minutes..., i'm making fiddle for it

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: Are you using `opacity` to hide the submenu for a good reason?

Comment: of course, i'd use `display:none` but in that way I can't have a clear transition (the display suddenly changes in 50%)

Comment: I see, use `visibility` like I show in my second answer. Maybe you need to play with the `transition` properties a little by including `visibility` with a delay, but that should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, not a real solution to your question, but maybe to your problem as far as I understand:

Why not using `visibility` for showing/hiding the menu? With `visibility: hidden` scroll bars will not be accessible until the menu is visible.

```css
#navigation>li>ul{
  /*...*/

  /*to hide it by default*/
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
}

/*hovers*/
#navigation>li:hover>ul{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmt9x1tw/).

By the way: `pointer-events` is not needed with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Only work around I can think of is wrapping it inside another `<div>` and let this one overflow. But it's clearly not a real solution, just a **work around**. Maybe this is even not possible in your case, you said your original code is complex.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  /*- overflow-y -*/
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.wrapper > div {
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #DDD;
  /*- pointer events -*/
  pointer-events: none;
}
.wrapper > div:hover {
  background: #D77;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    text
    <br/>text
    <br/>text
    <br/>text
    <br/>text
    <br/>text
    <br/>text
    <br/>text
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but I've to make It completely inactive , visible but not touchable, maybe an alternative to `pointer-events` for Firefox and old Operas could help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end goal is... but maybe this might help? http://codepen.io/ijmccallum/pen/reMYXN

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>text
  <br/>
    </div>
</div>

.parent {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  /*- overflow-y -*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*- pointer events -*/

}
.child {
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #DDD;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.parent:hover {
  background: #D77;
}
```

I just wrapped your div in a parent and restricted the dimensions of that. Scroll bar appears, no weird hover happening on the children.